# Nutch 1.7 with Hadoop 2.6.0 "Wrong FS" Error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nutch

We have been trying to use Nutch 1.7 with Hadoop 2.6.0.

After installation, we we try to submit a job to Nutch, we receive the following error:

```
INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://master:9000/user/ubuntu/crawl/crawldb/436075385, expected: file:///
```

Job is submitted using the following command:

```
./crawl urls crawl_results 1
```

Also, we have checked fs.default.name setting in core-site.xml is having hdfs protocol:

```
<property> 
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://master:9000</value> 
</property>
```

It is happening when crawl command is sent to Nutch, after it reads the input URLs from file and attempts to insert the data into crawl db.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution to this?